# Google Maps Api v3 - set map position in runtime

Tags: google-maps, position

How can I change position of the map, from where it is pointing now, to ie. 45.00,19.00, but in a runtime, now when map is initialized?

my application have to "jump" from some coordinates to other, so that's why I need this ability.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

ok, here it is:

```
MyMap.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng( 45, 19 ) );
```

Comment: Actually you don't have to access its map property. Just do 

`map.setCenter({ lat: yourLat,  lng: yourLng })`

Answer (score 12):

Create that Map object, save it to a variable (i.e. `map`) and then use `map.panTo()`.
See [the reference of Map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map)

Answer (score 1):

1. Define the place where to position
2. Pass that to map.setCenter()

```js
var map;

function initMap() {

    var container = document.getElementById('map');
    var options = {
        zoom: 18,
        gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(container, options);

    var myPlace = { lat: 23.7266, lng: 90.4216 };
    map.setCenter(myPlace);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

you need the extended MVCObject() ....
there you find getPosition() (return: LatLng)  and setPosition(latlng:LatLng)
you just need to set this property and map location will change